# What's Difference Between p and p[x] (Pointers in C)

Tags: c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int a[] = {1,2,3};
int *p = &a;

}
```

p = adress of a variable.
*p = The value in that adress.

I understand this but why p is memory adress but p[x] isn't?
For example if p = 987654321, i think p[0] should equals 9 or p[1] should equals 8 but they are not, they are equals 1 and 2 (a[0] and a[1]).

Comment: `p[x]` is the same as `*(p + x)`

Comment: `p = 987654321` What does that mean? Do you mean the address stored in `p` is the decimal value `987654321`?

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes i mean that.

Comment: The array-subscript operator `[]` always gives you *elements* in an *array*, or equivalently, the consecutive objects pointed to by a pointer.  But `[]` never lets you pluck out the digits of an integer, or a floating-point number, or a pointer value.

Comment: `int *p = &a;` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For starters this code snippet

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int *p = &a;
```

is incorrect. The expression `&a` has the pointer type `int ( * )[3]` while the type of the pointer `p` is `int *`. As these pointer types are not compatible the compiler should issue a diagnostic message for the record with the declaration of the pointer `p`.

It will be correctly to write either

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int ( *p )[3] = &a;
```

or

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int *p = a;
```

In the first case the expression `p[x]` has the array type `int[3]` that used in expressions with rare exception is converted to a pointer of the type `int *`. For example `p[0]` yields the array `a`. And this call of `printf`

```
printf( "p[0] = %p\n", ( void * )p[0] );
```

will output the address of the first element of the array `a`.

It is the same as to write

```
printf( "a = %p\n", ( void * )a );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int ( *p )[3] = &a;

    printf( "a = %p\n", ( void * )a );
    printf( "p[0] = %p\n", ( void * )p[0] );

    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "sizeof( a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );
    printf( "sizeof( p[0] ) = %zu\n", sizeof( p[0] ) );

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( p[0] ) / sizeof( *p[0] ); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", p[0][i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
a = 0x7fff034f5c1c
p[0] = 0x7fff034f5c1c

sizeof( a ) = 12
sizeof( p[0] ) = 12

1 2 3 
1 2 3
```

In the second case the expression `p[x]` has the type `int`. For example the expression `p[0]` is the first element of the array `a` and its value is `1`. The expression `p[1]` is the second element of the array `a` and its value is `2` and at last `p[2]` is the third element of the array `a` and its value is `3`.

Pay attention to that the expression `*p` is the same as `p[0]` and evaluates like `*( p + 0 )`.